# How managing multiple select controls on template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am looking for consult.
HTML:

```
<div id='masterBlock'>
   <div combo-box id='divComboBox1' ng-if='isShow1'>
      <select id='selectData2'>
         <option ng-repeat='item in dataArr1'>{{ item.name }}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div combo-box id='divComboBox2' ng-if='isShow2'>
      <select id='selectData2'>
         <option ng-repeat='item in dataArr2'>{{ item.size }}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.directive('comboBox', ['data', function(data) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {                
                $(element).find('select').combobox().on('change', function(eventObj) {
                    switch($(this)[0].id) {
                        case 'selectData1': selectData1Change(eventObj); break;
                        case 'selectData2': selectData2Change(eventObj); break;
                        default: break; 
                    }                                                                       
                });
                //
                function selectData1Change(eventObj) {
                    alert('1');
                }
                //
                function selectData2Change(eventObj) {
                    alert('2');
                }
            }
        }
    }])
```

Two 'div' blocks have same directive 'combo-box'. In directive I set on 'select' elements jQuery-UI combobox plugin and set chenge function. If needed I used ng-if to hide div#divComboBox1 or div#divComboBox2, 'div' block that stay visible managing by directive. I can set directive 'combo-box' on div#masterBlock, but in this case I have some problems with managing hide/display block inside it. In directive $(element).find('select').length => 0, becouse ng-if work quicker then directive. How I should do? to avoid future problems.

Comment: You can start by giving distinct `id`s to your `select` and `div` elements .

Comment: To expand on @X.L.Ant  comment, you have duplicate `id`s on elements.  This is invalid HTML, all `id` values in a document _must_ be unique.  Any JavaScript operating on HTML with duplicate ids has undefined behavior, which usually manifests as operating on the first of an id only.  Use `class` to operate on multiple elements instead.

Comment: with IDs my mistake. I misstype code) IDs unique to all blocks.